# Tags still remaining after using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, sockets, simplexml

I am using `simplexml_load_string` for XML packets. In my scenario, the XML string I want to convert is known as k.
My problem, however, is that when I use k, tags still remain that weren't parsed (`<k>, <\k>`).

For example, I use
`$x->k`, and I get back `<k>DATA I WANT HERE<\EK>`.
How do I get rid of these?

What the code does: It connects to a game and logs in.

Comment: Add your code, otherwise it's not clear what your problem really is. I guess it's pretty trivial to solve then.

Comment: This is the packet I'm trying to get k from                        <msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'><k>qH~e9Gmt</k></body></msg>, but the tags are included when I get it via simplexml

Comment: Add that to your question. And also show your PHP code. Otherwise it's not clear what `$x` is for example. Just add it, shorten it if necessary.

Comment: btw. I recommend you using python for parsing xml/html, it's easier and better

Comment: @user1432856 Your PHP code is wrong.  It should be `(string)$x->body->k`.

Answer (score 0):

Use *InnerNode* to get the value without the tags:

```
$x->k->InnerNode
```

You can also do a typecast:

```
(string)$x->k
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it seems those do not seem to work. I get          <K \>data<EK \> when I use Innernode/typecast.

Comment: @user1432856 wait .. you get **<K \>data<EK \>**?  That's different than what the question says ...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if I represented what I was trying to say inaccurately, I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: @user1432856 No worries, it's just that the solution would have to be different.  But why don't you just do like a string replace to get rid of those tags?

Comment: Then use `strip_tags` to remove the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and seem to be getting the string.

```
<?php
$str = "<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'><k>qH~e9Gmt</k></body></msg>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $str );
echo $xml->body->k; // gives 'qH~e9Gmt'
?>
```